# Arduino Struct with variable Char Array

Tags: struct, arduino

I try to fill a struct object with a variable Char Array, but it doesn't work.
The result are random symbols.

If I enter the "naamBestand"manually in the MyObject Temp, the correct answer will come out. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct MyObject {
  char bestandsnaam[12];
  int beginpositie;
  int lengte;
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  updateEEPROM(0, "test", 1, 1);
}

void loop() {
}

void updateEEPROM(int locatie, char naamBestand[12], int positieBestand, int lengteBestand) {
  MyObject temp {naamBestand, positieBestand , lengteBestand};
  Serial.println(temp.bestandsnaam);
  //EEPROM.put(locatie, temp);
}
```

Comment: if you want to copy text into the member `bestandsnaam` you have to do that: `strcpy`

Comment: How should I do that in the updateEEPROM function?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Comment: Thanks it worked! I found my solution here: (https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=353123.0)

Answer (score 0):

The solution!

```
typedef struct MyObject {
  char bestandsnaam[12];
  int beginpositie;
  int lengte;
};MyObject customVar;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  updateEEPROM(0, "test", 1 , 2);
}

void loop() {
}

void updateEEPROM(int locatie, char naamBestand[12], int positieBestand, int lengteBestand) {
  strcpy(customVar.bestandsnaam, naamBestand);
  customVar.beginpositie = positieBestand;
  customVar.lengte = lengteBestand;
  Serial.println(customVar.bestandsnaam);
  //EEPROM.put(locatie, customVar);
```